# How to reuse a bitmap on android

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I have the following code:

```
    public void loop1(int times, SpriteObject[] obj){
        for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
            obj[i] = new SpriteObject(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gv.getResources(),  R.drawable.bar1), 500,720);
        }
     }
```

However, when I draw this on the view it does not stay as i expected. 
If I use obj[i].setX(10) and obj[5].setX(20). Only the second one appears as it is refreshing and only taking the last object. is it possible to reuse the drawables like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you're trying to accomplish here and to me it seems like your resource load method is completely set up wrong. From what I can tell, you're trying to make two similar bitmaps move around.

First, for simple drawing applications or games you would use view or surfaceview so you must implement that. Secondly, the way I create moving bitmaps is to first create Bitmap variables to hold the respective bitmaps and then I create a separate classes for each respective Bitmap. In the classes I have the following.

`public float x = 0;`
`public float y = 0;`

So with this in mind all you have to do to draw the bitmaps is in the onDraw method of `View` you use this method.
`canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapVariable, bitmap.x, bitmap.y, null);`

If you wanted to move the bitmaps you would just have to change the X and Y of the respective bitmap. Either in a separate method or in your update loop.

Ultimately, I think you're understanding bitmaps wrong. Once created you don't need to recreate it to redraw it at a different location unless the bitmap was garbage collected.

Comment: You didn't understand my question right then. I have a code up and running. No problem with that. I have all of that set up. However, I don't intend to move a bitmap in the screen, but place it next to eacher other. But instead of it staying on screen it moves along.

Imagine X is my bitmap. I want to loop and print on the screen:

    >X first time
    >XX second time
    >XXX third time...

But what I am getting is:

    >X first time
    > X second time
    >   X third time

Comment: Could you show a little more of your code? Its hard to tell whats going on wrong with what you have posted. Whats calling the method and how the variables involved have been instantiated would be helpful

Comment: just think that every obj[i] is something I draw on screen. First i draw obj[0] at x=500, y=720. Then obj[1] at x=520, y=720, obj[2] at x=540, y=720 and so on...

Even though I create new object of that bitmap:

obj[i] = new SpriteObject(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gv.getResources(),  R.drawable.bar1), 500,720);

It still treats it as the same object.. I think it might be something with the bitmap on drawable rather than in my code...

Comment: In your code when you call the method you're creating a new object at the same location. `(500,720)` perhaps if you modify your code to `(500 + i * 20, 720)` you would get the results you were looking for. But in my opinion how you're drawing things might work currently but will definitely cause you many headaches in the future.

Comment: I already found the problem. I dont even need to have an array of the same bitmap. I can reuse the same. The problem is on the draw(canvas) method. I have now a for loop on my draw, so I draw the previous images that I firstly displayed!
Thx for trying to help me ;D